# Htaccess redirect URL to another one and delete characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want an old website to be redirect to the new one, the URL looks like this : `https://test.fr/directory/homepage.html`
In my .htaccess file I have :

```
RedirectPermanent / https://google.com/`
```

But what it does : `https://google.com/directory/homepage.html`

I'd like to redirect to `https://google.com/` and delete everything after the `.com/` but I have no idea how.

Comment: Please do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewrite ^ https://google.com/ [R=301,END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server for that. This usually is the case, certainly for all hosting providers.

If you only want to redirect that specific URL inside your http host, then that should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewrite ^/?directory/homepage\.html$ https://google.com/ [R=301,END]
```

You can implement such directives in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). You should prefer the actual http server's host configuration though, if you have access to that.

Comment: Why are you using `END` flag on a redirect rule?

Comment: @AmitVerma Some time ago I have been surprised myself that without an `L` or `END` flag the redirection does _not_ always work. I have no idea why... from the documentation I understand that an external redirection will _always_ terminate the rewriting process immediately, which might make sense. But as said: I stumbled about two cases where this did not work without a terminating flag. Whyever.

Comment: Arkascha , you are right but as far I understand `END`  terminates the internal redirection. Using it with a redirect rule is same as using `L` . END has no effect when it's used with `R`  .

Comment: @AmitVerma Yes, it has the same effect as an `L` flag here. I prefer the `END` flag in general, since it appears more transparent to me. It is clear what is going to happen. No other rewriting rule jumping in one did not think of in that moment.

Comment: @AmitVerma Thanks. Are you able to explain why an `L` or `END` flag is _sometimes_ required for an external redirection? I never really understood that myself ...

Comment: Arakscha, I often test RewriteRules with or without flags on different versions of Apache but I never see any difference. Rules work same even if you don't use flags.

Comment: @AmitVerma Thanks. That is my understanding too. I remember being very surprised some 3 years ago when I stumbled over two cases where that indeed made a difference. Unfortunately I do not remember the details. My bad.